# Hiding Driving Directions in Bing Maps API

Tags: html, bing-api, bing-maps

I want to hide the driving directions and only want to render the route in Bing Map.
Which DirectionsRequestOptions or other option do i need to set.
I believe(not sure) that those HTMl are associated with PushpinOptions options. 
I made the visible option false there to made it go away.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I got the reply in MS forums so posting the answer .. may be useful to someone else.

"Try not setting the itineraryContainer option in the render options."